# MongoDB - How to reference document's field value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Documents look like this:

```
[{
  quantity, 15,
  limit: 15
},
{
  quantity: 4,
  limit: 5
},
{
  quantity: 3,
  limit: 3,
}]
```

I need to find a document whose `quantity` is less than its `limit`. All documents have different quantities and limits.

How can I find a document whose `quantity` is less than its `limit` without knowing the document's `limit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with `$expr` to access the field value and use of aggregation operator.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $lt: [
      "$quantity",
      "$limit"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Query)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oXan6tF_gQB)

---

For aggregation query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $lt: [
          "$quantity",
          "$limit"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Aggregation Query)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hPyGlPdplS1)

Comment: thank you, it worked. Also I found it works with just `$lt: ["$prop1", "$prop2"]`